# Tracking changes in an array using Mongoid History

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

How do you track changes in an array using the Mongoid History gem? I have an array of questions. It will look something like this

```
Questions = [ {"intro" => "Intro: 1", "name" => "Name: 1"}, {"intro" => "Intro: 2", "name" => "Name: 2"} ]
```

This is my code

```
class Script
  include Mongoid::History::Trackable

  field :name, type: String
  field :type, type: String
  field :questions, type: Array, default: []

  track_history on: [ :type, :name, :questions ], track_create: true, track_update: true, track_destory: true
end

class Question
  include Mongoid::History::Trackable

  field :intro, type: String
  field :name, type: String

  track_history(
    on: :fields,
    scope: :script,
    track_create: true,
    track_update: true,
    track_destroy: true
  )
end
```

When I make a change, it gives me the array with all the information, instead of just the name or intro that changed. I do not want to have the questions embedded into the script for various reasons. The best way in my case is to create a field for it.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: If not you can raise an issue on the gem. Someone can raise a PR if it looks a genuine requirement.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment. I don't think it's a problem with the gem. It's just something, that it doesn't do. Would have to write some methods in order to make this work. Thank you.